# RestTemple custom error handler not catching ResourceAccessException

Tags: spring, error-handling, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to make Http connection to get data from external APIs. For this I have implemented a custom error handler and set it on the restTemplate object. Below is my custom error handler

```
public class CustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        int rawStatusCode = response.getRawStatusCode();
        if (rawStatusCode / 200 != 1) {
            LOG.debug("HTTPS hasError - " + rawStatusCode + "; " + response.getStatusText() + "; " + response.getStatusCode());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        int rawStatusCode = response.getRawStatusCode();
        LOG.debug("HTTPS handleError - " + rawStatusCode + "; " + response.getStatusText() + "; " + response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

and my RestTemplateUtils class looks like below

```
public class RestTemplateUtils {
RestTemplate restTemplate;
public ResponseEntity<String> restGet(String url) {
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new CustomResponseErrorHandler());
        ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        return response;
    }
}
```

I expect that any error that gets thrown during the `restTemplate.getForEntity()` call should be caught and logged by the `CustomResponseErrorHandler` but that is not the case. When I pass in a non-existent url `ResponseEntity<String> response= restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);` throws ResourceAccessException. What should I do if I want my custom error handler to catch a 404 in such a case? Am I  missing something here or misunderstanding how custom error handler should work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you completely give a non existing url then I don't think the code is going to the point where error handler is executed;
Looking at `RestTemplate#doExecute`

```
doExecute(URI url, @Nullable HttpMethod method, @Nullable RequestCallback requestCallback,
            @Nullable ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor)
```

code

```
try {
            ClientHttpRequest request = createRequest(url, method);
            if (requestCallback != null) {
                requestCallback.doWithRequest(request);
            }
            response = request.execute();
            handleResponse(url, method, response);
            return (responseExtractor != null ? responseExtractor.extractData(response) : null);
        }
```

`handleResponse` is where the error handler is looked for but I think yours is erroring out at `request.execute();`

Provide some non existing url on the server api path, then you would recieve a 404 from the server and your custom error handler gets executed.

Comment: What does server API path mean here? Where would I give that in my existing code?

Comment: like the actual endpoint you are trying to communicate to, but non existing resource

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? I am sorry if I don't completely understand you. Lets say my url is "www.abc.com/api/1.0/default",  isn't that what I am passing to the server api path?

Comment: You have not shown what the actual url is and what you are trying to test

Comment: I am trying to test my custom exception handler here if it shows the status codes in different scenarios. So one case was to pass the API url but instead of '.edu', I changed it to '.com'. I expected the custom exception error handler to give me some error code but instead I got a ResourceAccessException

Comment: yeah, because .com is not reachable your custom handler will not get a chance to execute. what you have to do is test with some non existing url or endpoint on .edu itself

Comment: Thank you so much. I did as u said and modified the url endpoint. The custom exception handler still did not get executed. In the console I got this message from RestTemplate ```WARN  RestTemplate:608 - GET request for "https://abc.edu/search/api/1.0/default/modules" resulted in 404 (Not Found); invoking error handler``` (instead of abc.edu it is the actual url there)

Comment: I can see errors on my side, but I logged it INFO level, make sure your logger level is configured to log debug messages. `INFO CustomResponseErrorHandler:16- HTTPS hasError - 404; Not Found; 404
INFO CustomResponseErrorHandler:31- HTTPS handleError - 404; Not Found; 404`

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes my logger level was not set to debug. I can now see my error messages from the custom error handler